# Consistent symbology across raster and vector files

Tags: qgis, shapefile, symbology, geotiff-tiff

If I have a shapefile and a GeoTIFF which both represent the same underlying geography. In particular, the shapefile was made by polygonizing the GeoTIFF. The shapefile has the pixel values of the originating set of pixels in the attribute table. The GeoTIFF stores floating point values (attribute table of the shapefile as well). I would like to apply symbology to these two files so that they appear roughly the same when viewed in QGIS. How can I accomplish this?

Right now I am using rule based styling for my shapefile. It appears exactly as I would like it to. The ranges for the filters that I defined are inclusive on the lower value of the range (e.g. 0 <= x < 1). I am trying to apply the same styling to the TIFF using the singleband pseudocolor setting. However, this only allows ranges inclusive of the higher end of the range.

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared example data. Currently I have no real idea what you have and where you want to go to.

Comment: Do you have the colors code extracted from the GeoTIFF inside the Shapefile ?

Comment: @Erik sorry, I cannot share the source data and I haven't had time to mock up something. I will try editing the question to be more explicit with an example soon

Comment: @GIS no, the GeoTIFF is single band, my aim is to have the color for the pixel be determined by an externally defined legend, e.g. if the pixel has a value between 0 and 10 the color should be (162, 0, 0). the same lat and lon in the shapefile has a feature with the pixel value stored in the attribute table